# Implicit initialization by argument deduction for a templated class array

Tags: c++, templates, initialization, aggregate-initialization, copy-initialization

I have an item class, thats really a wrapper around an int.
I have a templated node class. I pass item class to it as template parameter.

I want to create an array of the templated node class, but compiler does not like it.
When I create a single object using the same syntax, it works.
Why cant it deduce the array elements to initialize array of templated class?
What is the correct way of creating an array of objects of a templated class?

Heres item class, which is a wrapper around an `int`.

```
using namespace std;

class bItem {
private :     
    int item{INT_MIN};
public:
    bItem() : item(INT_MIN) {}
    bItem(int val) : item(val) {}
    int getItem() { return item; }
    bItem operator==(const bItem& val) {
        return item == val.item;
    }
    bItem operator>(const bItem& val) {
        return item > val.item;
    }
    bItem operator<(const bItem& val) {
        return item < val.item;
    }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const bItem& item) {
        os << "value:" << item.item << endl;
        return os;
    }
};
```

Heres the templated Node class

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template<class itemType>
class bNode {
    itemType item{};
    bNode* prev{};
    bNode* next{};
public:
    bNode() : item(), prev(nullptr), next(nullptr) {}
    bNode(itemType _item) : item(_item), prev(nullptr), next(nullptr) {}
    ~bNode() {
        delete prev;
        delete next;
    }
    
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const bNode& node) {
        os << "node " << node.item<< endl;
        return os;
    }
};
```

and heres the `main()`

```
int main()
{    
    bNode<bItem> nodes[5]{ 1,2,3,4,5 }; //this does not compile
    bNode<bItem> node2(6); //this compiles ok

}
```

and here is the error message

```
error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'int' to 'bNode<bItem>'
message : No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) of array, the elements are [copy-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) from the corresponding clause of the initializer list. That means the element with type `bNode<bItem>` needs to be copy-initialized from the `int`, which requires two user-defined implicit conversions, from `int` to `bItem` and from `bItem` to `bNode`, which is not allowed.

> Each `direct public base, (since C++17)` array element, or non-static class member, in order of array subscript/appearance in the class definition, is [copy-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) from the corresponding clause of the initializer list.

As the workaround you could impose restrictions on the times of implicit conversions, e.g.

```
bNode<bItem> nodes[5] = { bItem(1),bItem(2),bItem(3),bItem(4),bItem(5) };
```

Or you can add another constructor taking `int` to `bNode`, then it could be copy-initialized from `int` too.

```
// forward it to bNode::bNode(itemType)
bNode(int val) : bNode(itemType(val)) {}
```

BTW: `bNode<bItem> node2(6);` performs [direct initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization), which requiers only one implicit conversion (from `int` to `bItem`), and the converted `bItme` is passed to the constructor of `bNode` to construct `node2`. It doesn't have such issue as [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization#Notes). (Copy-initialization like `bNode<bItem> node2 = 6;` doesn't work either.)

> In addition, the implicit conversion in copy-initialization must produce T directly from the initializer, while, e.g. direct-initialization expects an implicit conversion from the initializer to an argument of T's constructor.

Comment: I am really hoping to find a way to modify the node class to enable the kind of initialization I have in my main().

Comment: @bsobaid You can add a constructor in `bNode`, see revised answer.

Comment: thx songyuanyao. appreciate your detailed response and explaination. In bNode(int val) I am explicitly stating the type i-e int. May be this is the only way. but I think I am going to play with copy constructors to see if I find anything.

Comment: @bsobaid You could define a template constructor for `bNode` that takes any type of argument and passes it to the `item` constructor. Like this: `template<class ArgType> bNode(ArgType&& Arg) : item(std::forward<ArgType>(Arg)) {}`